# Capture DNS traffic to and from a network namespace using tshark

Tags: network-namespaces, wireshark, tshark

How can I capture traffic specifically from a network interface inside a network namespace using `tshark`? In my case, the network interface `tun0` is moved into the network namespace called `vpn`.

Normally running `tshark -f "port 53"` clutters the output because it includes DNS queries from the main interface that the network namespace ends up using.

This is my network namespace setup (for what it's worth, this is from the openvpn netns-up script here: http://www.naju.se/articles/openvpn-netns.html)

```
$ ip netns add vpn
$ ip netns exec vpn ip link set dev lo up
$ ip link set dev tun0 up netns vpn mtu 1500
$ ip netns exec vpn ip addr add dev tun0 "10.14.0.3/16"

$ ip netns exec vpn ip addr add dev tun0 "$ifconfig_ipv6_local"/112

$ ip netns exec vpn ip route add default via 10.14.0.1

$ ip netns exec vpn ip route add default via "$ifconfig_ipv6_remote"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just continue with the same unshortened syntax you were using for executing a command inside a network namespace created with `ip netns add`:

```
ip netns exec vpn <command-for-capture>
```

Like:

```
ip netns exec vpn tshark -i tun0 -n -f 'port 53'
```

Note `tshark`'s option `-n` to avoid triggering DNS resolution, especially important when capturing DNS traffic, without which cascading DNS resolutions and captures caused by `tshark` itself would pollute original traffic.

As a side note, the `ip` command itself has a shortcut allowing to replace `ip netns exec FOO ip BAR ...` with `ip -n FOO BAR ...`, but of course this can't be used for any other command. A lot of OP's setup can be shortened into `ip -n vpn ...` instead of `ip netns exec vpn ip ...`.